# Android GridView stretchMode with Async ImageView Loading

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have the following GridView defined w/stretchMode set to "columnWidth".

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="160dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
/>
```

Each item in the GridView is structured as follows.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/videoGridItemImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/videoGridItemDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"    
            android:background="#88000000"
            android:textColor="#F1F1F1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:padding="2dp"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/videoGridItemTitle" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="#F1F1F1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="#88000000"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/videoGridItemSubtitle" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" 
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="#88000000"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the GridView's adapter, I'm async loading and displaying the images by passing the url and reference of the ImageView to a dedicated class.  The class downloads the image into a bitmap and then updates the ImageView using setImageBitmap().  This workflow functions as expected; however, my images aren't filling the entire width of the ImageView.  There's a small amount of paddding on the left/right sides.  I realize that I can use scaleType="fitXY", but this isn't ideal as it skews the images.  Setting the src attribute of ImageView to a local image scales just fine with stretchMode="columnWidth".  My guess is that the ImageView is scaling to the original columnWidth and not the stretched/dynamic width. Does anyone have any insight as to why this is occurring and/or how to fix?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Set your ImageView's layout_width to wrap_content. The ImageView will resize based on the size of the image and your column will adjust accordingly.
2. Set your ImageView's scaleType to centerCrop. This will try to fit the image into the imageview without skewing it and will just cut off any excess that doesn't fit. This will leave no blank space.

Comment: 1.  Setting the ImageView's layout_width to wrap_content just put all the padding on the right side - as apposed to half on the left and half on the right.  The ImageView still does not fill the entire width of the column as desired.

Comment: 2.  Setting the ImageView's scaleType to centerCrop does fix the skewing problem that was caused by fitXY; however, it crops the image which is not ideal either.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue is with stretchMode="columnWidth".  If I use any other value for stetchMode (including "none"), the images are displayed as expected - no cropping/skewing and filling the entire column width.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  My solution was to override the ImageView (in my case) FrameLayout to set it's height prior to image download.  I wanted square tiles enforced in my GridView, and accomplished like so:

```
public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

  public SquareFrameLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }
  public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }
  public SquareFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
  }
}
```

Each GridView item is this:

```
<com.my.client.ui.layout.SquareFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/discovery_tile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/my_desc" />

</com.my.client.ui.layout.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Then in the GridView I used this:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.my.client.ui.MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/my_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="0px"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0px"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="fill" />
```